# Android: supports-screens is ignored by Android Market

Tags: android, manifest

I specifically turned off support for large and x-large screens in the manifest file for my app before I uploaded it to the Android Market because the code path for these is broken (I'm currently working on a 'Tablet' version of my app). I know it's broken, that's why I turned off support. So why oh why is the Android Market ignoring this in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="false"
   android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

and letting people with large screen devices see the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that just tells the device to show the app in compatibility mode.  It doesn't prevent the app from running.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

"Beware that setting it "false" will generally enable screen compatibility mode."