# trigger.io - Support only Android tablets

Tags: android, trigger.io

The iOS side of things in trigger.io allows me to select iPhone, iPad or both when I'm setting the configuration for an app.  I know that you can change your AndroidManifest.xml file under normal circumstances to add something like the following

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Is it possible to edit my AndroidManifest.xml file, so when I upload to the Play Store, only tablet devices are allowed to download and install my application?  I've tried to edit the one in the forge-workspace//development/ folder, but no luck.

*I have trigger.io installed on a Mac, so paths that relate to a Windows install will be of no use to me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you used `forge build` to build your app, you'll find it in the following directory:

```
forge-workspace/development/android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Afterwards you can use `forge package` to get the app ready for the Play Store. Make sure to edit the manifest file before using forge package and keep it mind that you have to apply those changes each time.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, the only thing is I've done this, yet when I upload my app to the Play Store, it tells me that small, normal, large and xlarge screens are supported, when my manifest was altered to contain the block above, between `<uses-sdk>` and `<application>`

Comment: Can you take the resulting .apk file and change its type to .zip (just change the file name). Unzip it and see if the changes are applied to the AndroidManifest.xml in there. The location you put the tag in should be fine, as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) says it is to be used as a children of <manifest>.

Comment: Maybe this post also helps to figure out why they are still "supported": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031379/android-supports-screens-is-ignored-by-android-market

Comment: The link is helpful background, but it doesn't really solve the problem.
I tried renaming and opening the .zip file and my `AndroidManifest` is a bit of a garbled mess (the formatting has changed - no <> characters, etc.) but there is no reference to the supports-screens or the values that I have set.